# How we define the id in kotlin without any use of third party library?

Tags: android, kotlin

In java, we used to define the id by using findviewbyid. I am Wondering how we can define the id in kotlin without any use of third party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to define the view id's in Kotlin. All you have to do is use a non declared variable which has same name as the view in layout xml file. This reduces the chance of you running into a bug.

Assume you have this `TextView` in the layout xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

then this is how you can access this by a variable name `mytextview`, without declaring it in the file. This is how you would set the text

```
mytextview.text = "My text view"
```

You can read more at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

---

Another way could be following but I wouldn't suggest it

```
private var textview: TextView? = null
textview = findViewById(R.id.mytextview) as TextView // old way
textview  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mytextview) // new way
```

Comment: textview  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mytextview) // new way
This also work for me.great help.Thank you

Comment: Seems I can't access it by variable `mytextview`. Not sure what I missed. There is no auto completion. And the variable is treated as not declared. Do I need to import something? `findViewById` works for me.